# Pandas corr() returning NaN too often

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, correlation

I'm attempting to run what I think should be a simple correlation function on a dataframe but it is returning NaN in places where I don't believe it should.

**Code:**

```
# setup
import pandas as pd
import io

csv = io.StringIO(u'''
id  date    num
A   2018-08-01  99
A   2018-08-02  50
A   2018-08-03  100
A   2018-08-04  100
A   2018-08-05  100
B   2018-07-31  500
B   2018-08-01  100
B   2018-08-02  100
B   2018-08-03  0
B   2018-08-05  100
B   2018-08-06  500
B   2018-08-07  500
B   2018-08-08  100
C   2018-08-01  100
C   2018-08-02  50
C   2018-08-03  100
C   2018-08-06  300
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep = '\t')

# Format manipulation
df = df[df['num'] > 50]
df = df.pivot(index = 'date', columns = 'id', values = 'num')
df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())

# Main correlation calculations
print df.iloc[:, 1:].corr()
```

**Subject DataFrame:**

```
       A      B      C
0    NaN  500.0    NaN
1   99.0  100.0  100.0
2    NaN  100.0    NaN
3  100.0    NaN  100.0
4  100.0    NaN    NaN
5  100.0  100.0    NaN
6    NaN  500.0  300.0
7    NaN  500.0    NaN
8    NaN  100.0    NaN
```

**corr() Result:**

```
    A    B    C
A  1.0  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  1.0  1.0
C  NaN  1.0  1.0
```

According to the (limited) [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) on the function, it should exclude "NA/null values".  Since there are overlapping values for each column, should the result not all be non-NaN?

There are good discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619578/numpy-corrcoef-compute-correlation-matrix-while-ignoring-missing-data), but neither answered my question.  I've tried the `float64` idea discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453337/python-cannot-make-corr-work), but that failed as well.

@hellpanderr's comment brought up a good point, I'm using 0.22.0

*Bonus question - I'm no mathematician, but how is there a 1:1 correlation between B and C in this result?*

Comment: `pandas=0.23.4` gives me `[[1.0, nan, 0.9998469895178864],
 [nan, 1.0, 0.9819805060619657],
 [0.9998469895178864, 0.9819805060619657, 1.0]]`

Comment: I might have tweaked it a little, I just updated the code (`> 50` instead of `> 10`) which gives me the same result as I posted. Not sure if that changes things on your end.

Comment: Now I get the same result as you.

Comment: And if you try to do it manually with `df.cov()[['C','B']] / df.std()[['C','B']].product()`?

Comment: Now you're getting into the "I'm no mathematician" part of my post.  Really don't know. I'm a little out of my depth when it comes to the core statistical calculations.

Comment: After a little research (and this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94152), it appears that correlation between two, two-number arrays will always be 1:1.  So that answers the bonus question, but not the main NaN issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result seems to be an artefact of the data you work with. As you write, `NA`s are ignored, so it basically boils down to:

```
df[['B', 'C']].dropna()

       B      C
1  100.0  100.0
6  500.0  300.0
```

So, there are only two values per column left for the calculation which should therefore [lead to to correlation coefficients of `1`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94150/why-is-the-pearson-correlation-1-when-only-two-data-values-are-available/94152#94152):

```
df[['B', 'C']].dropna().corr()

     B    C
B  1.0  1.0
C  1.0  1.0
```

So, where do the `NA`s then come from for the remaining combinations?

```
df[['A', 'B']].dropna()

       A      B
1   99.0  100.0
5  100.0  100.0


df[['A', 'C']].dropna()

       A      C
1   99.0  100.0
3  100.0  100.0
```

So, also here you end up with only two values per column. The difference is that the columns `B` and `C` contain only one value (`100`) which gives a standard deviation of `0`:

```
df[['A', 'C']].dropna().std()

A    0.707107
C    0.000000
```

When the correlation coefficient is calculated, you divide by the standard deviation, which leads to a `NA`.

Comment: Cleb - thanks for doing the heavy lifting, I think you nailed it with that last part about the standard deviations.  Accepted.

Comment: @elPastor: Glad I could help. I should put a short troubleshooting section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns/42580124#42580124) and refer to your question.