# Correlation matrix returning NaN values from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, correlation

I have a couple of large datasets that I need to find the correlation between. The data is converted into a panda dataframe and I use pd.DataFrame.corr() to find the correlation. It works for some datasets and not for others, and I am unsure why.

Values in the datasets that do not work are not the same, so the S.D is not 0.
The column types (dtype) of the dataFrame objects are all float64.

The code works with:

```
                               BPM1401-01:x  BPM1401-01:y
2019-07-23 05:59:59.641471863      0.000052     -0.000108  
2019-07-23 06:00:00.033471822      0.000050     -0.000108  
2019-07-23 06:00:00.425471783           NaN     -0.000108  
2019-07-23 06:00:00.816471815      0.000051           NaN  
2019-07-23 06:00:01.170471907      0.000050           NaN  
2019-07-23 06:00:01.954471827      0.000049           NaN  
2019-07-23 06:00:02.345471859      0.000051           NaN  
2019-07-23 06:00:02.737471819      0.000051     -0.000108  
2019-07-23 06:00:03.090471745      0.000052     -0.000108  
2019-07-23 06:00:03.481471777      0.000051     -0.000109
```

but does not work with:

```
                               SR1:BPMXRMSGlobal  SR1:BPMYRMSGlobal
2019-07-23 05:59:58.197318077           1.096721                NaN  
2019-07-23 05:59:58.197477102                NaN           1.586067  
2019-07-23 06:00:01.471035957                NaN           0.772168  
2019-07-23 06:00:02.132909060           1.553643                NaN  
2019-07-23 06:00:02.132987022                NaN           1.209081  
2019-07-23 06:00:02.793922901           2.558707                NaN  
2019-07-23 06:00:02.793971062                NaN           1.624215  
2019-07-23 06:00:03.440277100           2.508732                NaN  
2019-07-23 06:00:03.440378904                NaN           1.540483  
2019-07-23 06:00:04.094022036           2.325517                NaN
```

```
import pandas as pd  
import seaborn as sb  
import numpy as np  

#Align the data using the timestamps, already done in the above sets.
def align_dataframes(data_frame_list):

    #Set progress to initial dataframe
    curr_df = data_frame_list[0]

    #Align all dataframes together and join
    for i in range(len(data_frame_list)-1):
        curr_df = curr_df.join(data_frame_list[i+1], how = 'outer')

    #Return aligned dataframe
    return(curr_df)

def plot_corr(data_frame):

    print(data_frame.dtypes) -> gives float64
    #Compute correlation matrix
    corr_mat = data_frame.corr(method = 'pearson',min_periods=1)
    heat_map = sb.heatmap(corr_mat, linewidths = .5)

    plt.show()
```

It seems to me like the second dataFrame should work just as well, but the corr() matrix ends up returning NaN values.

Comment: It is the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52466844/1534017), I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second dataframe has no row where both values are not null, therefor there are no datapoints upon which to find a correlation

Comment: Thank you very much! Would the best fix for this be interpolating the dataframe? I'm somewhat new to data analysis.