# correlation between two columns in pandas dataframe not working?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I follow this guide for correlation:

[Use .corr to get the correlation between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns)

here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 1, 1], 'b':[1, 1, 1, 1]})
print(df)
cor = df['a'].corr(df['b'])

print('the correlation:')
print(cor)
```

here is the result (dataframe two columns of 1):

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  1  1
the correlation:
nan
```

I am expecting correlation to be 1, but it is `nan`.  Why is this the case and how do i correct this ?

Comment: [Perhaps useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466844/pandas-corr-returning-nan-too-often).

Comment: there's no variation within a column

Comment: no std , so by the definition return NaN

Comment: appreciated,  just realised the same.  would i be able to show this is zero in place of nan ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though there is zero correlation here, and this would work with a different set of numbers.

so this would return a number:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'b':[1, 2, 3, 4]})
print(df)
cor = df['a'].corr(df['b'])

print('the correlation:')
print(cor)
```

returns 1