# How do you run correlation with missing data (NaN), without removing the entire row/imputing

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm trying to run a correlation and multivariate regression for a bunch of variables, some with missing values. I don't want to dropna() the entire row/column or imput data when it's missing, how can I simply skip a NaN value?

Example of my columns with NaN values:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy corrcoef - compute correlation matrix while ignoring missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619578/numpy-corrcoef-compute-correlation-matrix-while-ignoring-missing-data)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you can. Imputation is the approach usually. So it might be an extra step when you prep your dataset for this.